# Adding a field to users from a module.install file

Tags: entities

Is it possible to add a custom field to users from a module.install file, as it would be done from admin/config/people/accounts/fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, in the same way [forum_enable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--forum--forum.install/function/forum_enable/7) adds a new field to the "forum" content type; the only difference is that "entity_type" and "bundle" are both set to "user."

```
// Create the 'taxonomy_forums' field if it doesn't already exist.
if (!field_info_field('taxonomy_forums')) {
  $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'taxonomy_forums', 
    'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference', 
    'settings' => array(
      'allowed_values' => array(
        array(
          'vocabulary' => $vocabulary->machine_name, 
          'parent' => 0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  field_create_field($field);
}

// …

// Create the instance on the bundle.
$instance = array(
  'field_name' => 'taxonomy_forums', 
  'entity_type' => 'node', 
  'label' => $vocabulary->name, 
  'bundle' => 'forum', 
  'required' => TRUE, 
  'widget' => array(
    'type' => 'options_select',
  ), 
  'display' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference_link', 
      'weight' => 10,
    ), 
    'teaser' => array(
      'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference_link', 
      'weight' => 10,
    ),
  ),
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

You can implement a similar code in the `hook_enable()` implementation of your module, or in the `hook_install()` implementation; in the first case, you should check if the field doesn't already exists, or [field_create_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) raises an exception.

To verify the field doesn't already exist, you can use code similar to the following one, where `$instance` is the same array as used in the previous code:

```
$prior_instance = field_read_instance($instance['entity_type'], $instance['field_name'], $instance['bundle']);
if (empty($prior_instance)) {
  field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

Comment: What method in the install file would I put this in?

Comment: I corrected my answer: The bundle for user fields is "user"; if you don't set it, the code will raise a PHP exception.